# Как работают вложенные циклы на питон?

Tags: python, циклы

Как работает этот код? Каким образом получается такой результат? объясните, пожалуйста, максимально просто, с объяснением полученных цифр.

```
for i in range(1,6):
    for j in range (1,i+1):
        print(j, " ", end="")
    print()
```

1
1  2
1  2  3
1  2  3  4
1  2  3  4  5

Comment: [`for` Statements](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements), [The `range()` Function](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#the-range-function), [`print`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print)

Comment: А вы пробовали разобрать этот код? Ну там, что выдаёт `range(a, b)`, как работает `for`, что за параметр `end` у `print`? Разбираете всё по отдельности, потом складываете вместе, проходите циклы по бумажке, присваивая значения переменным... Именно так и можно что-то понять, потом проще будет.

Comment: пробовала, конечно.. я только начала изучать питон, в целом с циклом for разобралась, но вложенные циклы не хотят быстро укладываться в голове :)

Answer (score 1):

У вас есть 2 цикла. Первый - `for i in range(1,6)` он идёт от 1 до 5, а в качестве счётчика выступает переменная `i` внутри первого цикла есть второй - `for j in range (1,i+1)` он идёт от 1 до значения переменной `i+1`, то есть если `i=3`, то цикл будет идти от 1 до 3х `range(1,4) дает значения от 1 до 3`.Так как один цикл находится в другом, с каждой итерацией (кругом) цикла будут проходить все итерации вложенного цикла. Это можно сравнить с часами и минутами, где минуты - вложенный цикл в часы. Когда наступает новый час происходит 60 итераций минут, после чего завершается итерация 1 часа. Происходит переход на новый час и обнуление минут. В конкретно этой программе при первой итерации первого цикла значение `i = 1`, что означает, что второй цикл будет идти от 1 до 1, т.е. сработает 1 раз и выведет переменную `j` которая равна 1. При выводе `j` программа также выводит и пробел для того, чтобы если чисел 2 или более, они были разделены. Также в функции `print()` можно заметить параметр `end` который равен пустоте `end=""`, это сделано для того, чтобы после вывода `j` не было перехода на новую строку (по умолчанию параметр `end="\n"`. `\n` - оператор перехода на новую строку). После вывода всех чисел, производится переход на новую строку путём пустого принта `print()`. Как я выше писал пустой `print()` содержит `\n`, после чего операция повторяется с увеличенным значением `i`

Comment: спасибо большое!!! кажется я разобралась :))))